# Nested for-loops in xml parsing

Tags: python, parsing, xml, iteration, lxml

I wrote program that reads and processes xml files submitted by external users. The part of the code in question iterates over xml node's children, appends a dictionary - a future row in a table, and repeats the process for every child and its child and so on.

Exemplary xml node looks like this:

```
xmlstr =  '<Root_Level><Level1><Foo_A>1065106.46</Foo_A><Foo_B>675706.31</Foo_B><Foo_B1>0.00</Foo_B1><Level1_A><Foo_A>23750.00</Foo_A><Foo_B>0.00</Foo_B><Foo_B1>0.00</Foo_B1></Level1_A><Level1_B><Foo_A>1041356.46</Foo_A><Foo_B>675706.31</Foo_B><Foo_B1>0.00</Foo_B1><Level1_B_1><Foo_A>0.00</Foo_A><Foo_B>0.00</Foo_B><Foo_B1>0.00</Foo_B1></Level1_B_1><Level1_B_2><Foo_A>466158.93</Foo_A><Foo_B>59838.40</Foo_B><Foo_B1>0.00</Foo_B1><Level1_B_2_1><Foo_A>0.00</Foo_A><Foo_B>0.00</Foo_B><Foo_B1>0.00</Foo_B1></Level1_B_2_1><Level1_B_2_2><Foo_A>0.00</Foo_A><Foo_B>0.00</Foo_B><Foo_B1>0.00</Foo_B1></Level1_B_2_2></Level1_B_2></Level1_B><Level1_C><Foo_A>0.00</Foo_A><Foo_B>0.00</Foo_B><Foo_B1>0.00</Foo_B1></Level1_C><Level1_D><Foo_A>0.00</Foo_A><Foo_B>0.00</Foo_B><Foo_B1>0.00</Foo_B1></Level1_D></Level1><Level2><Foo_A>1065106.46</Foo_A><Foo_B>675706.31</Foo_B><Foo_B1>0.00</Foo_B1><Level2_A><Foo_A>556001.19</Foo_A><Foo_B>138410.82</Foo_B><Foo_B1>0.00</Foo_B1><Level2_A_1><Foo_A>50000.00</Foo_A><Foo_B>50000.00</Foo_B><Foo_B1>0.00</Foo_B1></Level2_A_1></Level2_A><Level2_B><Foo_A>509105.27</Foo_A><Foo_B>537295.49</Foo_B><Foo_B1>0.00</Foo_B1><Level2_B_1><Foo_A>0.00</Foo_A><Foo_B>0.00</Foo_B><Foo_B1>0.00</Foo_B1></Level2_B_1><Level2_B_2><Foo_A>0.00</Foo_A><Foo_B>0.00</Foo_B><Foo_B1>0.00</Foo_B1></Level2_B_2></Level2_B></Level2></Root_Level>’
```

Code I’ve written (brace yourself, it's pretty ugly):

```
# code to help you get started
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.fromstring(xmlstr)
tree.xpath('.')[0].getchildren()
xml_node = tree.xpath('.')[0]

# real use case starts here
table = []
tmp = {}
for b in xml_node:
    lvl = 0
    tag = b.tag
    txt = b.text

    table.append(tmp)
    tmp = {}
    tmp['lbl'] = tag
    tmp['lvl'] = lvl

    for elem in b.getchildren():
        lvl = 1
        tag = elem.tag
        txt = elem.text
        if tag.lower().strip().startswith('foo'):
            tmp[tag] = txt
        else:
            table.append(tmp)
            tmp = {}
            tmp['lbl'] = tag
            tmp['lvl'] = lvl

        for el in elem.getchildren():
            lvl = 2
            tag = el.tag
            txt = el.text
            if tag.lower().strip().startswith('foo'):
                tmp[tag] = txt
            else:
                table.append(tmp)
                tmp = {}
                tmp['lbl'] = tag
                tmp['lvl'] = lvl

            for e in el.getchildren():
                lvl = 3
                tag = e.tag
                txt = e.text
                if tag.lower().strip().startswith('foo'):
                    tmp[tag] = txt
                else:
                    table.append(tmp)
                    tmp = {}
                    tmp['lbl'] = tag
                    tmp['lvl'] = lvl

                for e in e.getchildren():
                    lvl = 4
                    tag = e.tag
                    txt = e.text
                    if tag.lower().strip().startswith('foo'):
                        tmp[tag] = txt
                    else:
                        table.append(tmp)
                        tmp = {}
                        tmp['lbl'] = tag
                        tmp['lvl'] = lvl

                    for e in e.getchildren():
                        lvl = 5
                        tag = e.tag
                        txt = e.text
                        if tag.lower().strip().startswith('foo'):
                            tmp[tag] = txt
                        else:
                            table.append(tmp)
                            tmp = {}
                            tmp['lbl'] = tag
                            tmp['lvl'] = lvl

                        for e in e.getchildren():
                            lvl = 6
                            tag = e.tag
                            txt = e.text
                            if tag.lower().strip().startswith('foo'):
                                tmp[tag] = txt
                            else:
                                table.append(tmp)
                                tmp = {}
                                tmp['lbl'] = tag
                                tmp['lvl'] = lvl

                            for e in e.getchildren():
                                lvl = 7
                                tag = e.tag
                                txt = e.text
                                if tag.lower().strip().startswith('foo'):
                                    tmp[tag] = txt
                                else:
                                    table.append(tmp)
                                    tmp = {}
                                    tmp['lbl'] = tag
                                    tmp['lvl'] = lvl


                                if e.getchildren():
                                   raise NotImplementedError

# make_sure_last_row_is_appended
try:
    if table[-1]['lbl'] != tag:
        table.append(tmp)
except KeyError:
    # probably table has only 1 row
    table.append(tmp)

# remove_technical_first_row
p = table.pop(0)
```

Output looks like this (as it should, there is no leeway regarding its structure):

```
[ {'lbl': 'Level1', 'lvl': 0, 'Foo_A': '1065106.46', 'Foo_B': '675706.31', 'Foo_B1': '0.00'}, {'lbl': 'Level1_A', 'lvl': 1, 'Foo_A': '23750.00', 'Foo_B': '0.00', 'Foo_B1': '0.00'}, {'lbl': 'Level1_B', 'lvl': 1, 'Foo_A': '1041356.46', 'Foo_B': '675706.31', 'Foo_B1': '0.00'}, {'lbl': 'Level1_B_1', 'lvl': 2, 'Foo_A': '0.00', 'Foo_B': '0.00', 'Foo_B1': '0.00'}, {'lbl': 'Level1_B_2', 'lvl': 2, 'Foo_A': '466158.93', 'Foo_B': '59838.40', 'Foo_B1': '0.00'}, {'lbl': 'Level1_B_2_1', 'lvl': 3, 'Foo_A': '0.00', 'Foo_B': '0.00', 'Foo_B1': '0.00'}, {'lbl': 'Level1_B_2_2', 'lvl': 3, 'Foo_A': '0.00', 'Foo_B': '0.00', 'Foo_B1': '0.00'}, {'lbl': 'Level1_C', 'lvl': 1, 'Foo_A': '0.00', 'Foo_B': '0.00', 'Foo_B1': '0.00'}, {'lbl': 'Level1_D', 'lvl': 1, 'Foo_A': '0.00', 'Foo_B': '0.00', 'Foo_B1': '0.00'}, {'lbl': 'Level2', 'lvl': 0, 'Foo_A': '1065106.46', 'Foo_B': '675706.31', 'Foo_B1': '0.00'}, {'lbl': 'Level2_A', 'lvl': 1, 'Foo_A': '556001.19', 'Foo_B': '138410.82', 'Foo_B1': '0.00'}, {'lbl': 'Level2_A_1', 'lvl': 2, 'Foo_A': '50000.00', 'Foo_B': '50000.00', 'Foo_B1': '0.00'}, {'lbl': 'Level2_B', 'lvl': 1, 'Foo_A': '509105.27', 'Foo_B': '537295.49', 'Foo_B1': '0.00'}, {'lbl': 'Level2_B_1', 'lvl': 2, 'Foo_A': '0.00', 'Foo_B': '0.00', 'Foo_B1': '0.00'}, {'lbl': 'Level2_B_2', 'lvl': 2, 'Foo_A': '0.00', 'Foo_B': '0.00', 'Foo_B1': '0.00'}]
```

The main problem with this code is that I don't have control over the input xml, so theoretically it can be more nested than I'll anticipate in my code. So far I wrote 'n'+3 for-loops with 'n' being the maximal nesting level observed in a test sample, but an input xml easily can be more nested that 'n'+3.

What I wrote was partly justified by being in a hurry, but to be honest I don't have an idea how to handle this more elegantly. I went through methods proposed in several articles (for example [this one](https://www.thepythoncorner.com/2017/12/the-art-of-avoiding-nested-code/?source=post_page-----ec8a780089b7----------------------) or [that one](https://medium.com/python-pandemonium/never-write-for-loops-again-91a5a4c84baf)), but nothing came to mind. Maybe this can be done with 'while True...break' statement or getchildren() method hidden in a generator function...

Also, it's important to maintain the data structure, so lxml._Element.iter() method instead of lxml._Element.getchildren() seems a bad idea.

So far performance wasn’t an issue.
At last stage of refactoring process I usually improve variable names and divide code into smallest possible functions with descriptive names as per ‘Clean Code’ methodology, so suggestions in this area while welcomed are secondary to the main problem.

How can I improve my code?

Comment: _"How can I improve my code?"_ Do some XSLT procesing before in 1st place.

Comment: Your code doesn't do what the question says it does. Is this because it is not implemented?

Comment: Quick suggestion: get all matching nodes with `tree.xpath("//*[starts-with(name(), 'Foo')]")` and then use `getparent()` to find the height of the node (or perhaps that's possible with XPath too).

Comment: Thanks @ferada, I'll try that. Can I use XPath() instead of xpath()? (see:https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-hiperfparse/)

Comment: I don't know, I meant XPath the standard, not the method. Seems to work fine for me with `tree.xpath`, but of course you can see if there's a more convenient/fast/... implementation.

Comment: @FreezePhoenix, what do you mean? I was trying to convay the goal of re-writing for-loops into something different... Is the title misleading?

Comment: Thanks @πάντα ῥεῖ for your suggestion. Could you elaborate on how would you transform xml via xsl? I’m not proficient in XSLT and it seems to me that I’ll be doing the same only using <xsl:for-each select=””>

Comment: @PawelKam Your title says it is not using nested for loops - however your code disagrees.

Comment: I edited the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to process recursively nested data is with recursively nested code.

I don't know Python, and I would do this in XQuery or XSLT by preference, but the pseudo-code is the same whatever the language:

```
function deep_process (parent, table, level) {
   for child in parent.children() {
        shallow_process(child, table, level)
        deep_process(child, table, level+1);
   }
}
```

where shallow_process() is whatever local processing you do at every level.

The key message to take away is that processing recursive data requires recursive code.